# Event between components vuejs / laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Any idea why my Event handler dont catch the value from select hastag?

This is my componente Notifications

```
export default {

      props: ['selected'],


      data: function() {

        return {

          message: 'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet',

          timeago: ' à 3 horas atás',

          hastags:[

            '#Advogado',

            '#ReformulaçãoPositiva',

            '#RetTesdt'

          ]

        };

      },

      created () {

        alert("Here")

        $eventBus.$on('teste', this.selected)

      }


    }
```

This is my Hastags Components

```
    export default {

      data: function() {

        return {

          hastags:[

            '#Advogado',

            '#EnviodeDocumentação',

            '#Upselling',

            '#ReformulaçãoPositiva',

            '#RetTesdt'

          ]

        };

      },

      methods : {

        randomNumber : function() {

          return 'h' + (Math.floor(Math.random() * 4) + 1)  ;

        },

          selectHastag: function (hastag) {

            this.selectedHastag = hastag

            eventBus.$emit('teste', this.selectedHastag);

        }
}
```

This is my root app.js

```
Vue.component('notifications', require('./components/Notifications.vue').default);
Vue.component('hastag', require('./components/Hastag.vue').default);
Vue.component('option-button', require('./components/OptionButton.vue').default);

window.eventBus = new Vue();

const app = new Vue({

    el: '#app'

});
```

any idea how the best practices to implement?

in this case it would be communication between child componenents.

Some help to implement, thank you very much.

Error:

> app.js:84610 [Vue warn]: Error in event handler for "teste": "TypeError: Cannot read property 'apply' of undefined" (found in )

Answer (score 1):

1. In the line

```
$eventBus.$on('teste', this.selected)
```

instead of this.selected there should be a handler at least an arrow function:

```
$eventBus.$on('teste', e => this.selected = e)
```

2. Don' try to change props that are passed from a parent component. If you wish to change a prop value you need to emit an event with a new value and a parent component has to catch this event and change a prop value to a new one (passed with an event).

Comment: Yes it worked. but it only works once, I wanted to click on it to change the value.

Comment: Did you try not to change prop directly?